# R linear model function with 3 catagories

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I have a data set with a column for a category that has 3 levels, and one with a value. For example:

`Cat | Val
 A  |  3.4
 B  |  2.3
 C  |  6.4
 B  |  3.1
 C  |  7.4
 A  |  6.7`

In R studio i want to do a statistical linear regression on the three levels. 
With the command

`lm(cat ~ val)`

With this command I only receive a result that includes estimate std, error t, etc. for 2 of the categories - A & B. What about C? How can i view the regressions properties for C aswell?

Comment: Presumably your results included a constant: that could be the C result with the A result in fact being the change from C to A and the B result being the change from C to B

Comment: Did you mean `lm(Val ~ Cat)` ?